# Converting enumeration to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> issue

Tags: c#, .net, enums, ienumerable

I am trying to use an enumeration to feed my Dropdownlist but I couldn't manage to convert it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

This is the code:

```
EducationStatusEnum[] values = (EducationStatusEnum[])Enum
                                     .GetValues(typeof(EducationStatusEnum));

var list = from value in values
     select new { Value = ((int)value).ToString() , Text = value.ToString()};


studentViewModel.LastEducationStatusList = list;
```

This is the error message:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic
>       .IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic
>       .IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. 
>       An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Am I at least on the right path? Are there any other conversion ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without a more complete code example. But I would expect this to work for you:

```
EducationStatusEnum[] values = (EducationStatusEnum[])Enum
                                     .GetValues(typeof(EducationStatusEnum));

var list = from value in values
     select new SelectListItem()
     {
         Value = ((int)value).ToString(),
         Text = value.ToString()
     };

studentViewModel.LastEducationStatusList = list;
```

In other words, from the error message it appears that the only problem here is that the enumeration type doesn't match the enumeration type expected for `LastEducationStatusList`. The error message says that it's trying to assign to`IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>`, so by using the actual `SelectListItem` type in the LINQ query instead of an anonymous type, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use
Pretty sure I got it off this site but I cannot find the post
Then just bind to the Dictionary with DisplayMemberPath as Value.
What is nice is that you have the actual enum in the Key

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> EnumToDictionary<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    // Can't use generic type constraints on value types,
    // so have to do check like this
    if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

    Dictionary<T, string> enumDL = new Dictionary<T, string>();
    foreach (T enm in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    {
        string name = Enum.GetName(enumType, enm);
        if (name != null)
        {
            FieldInfo field = enumType.GetField(name);
            if (field != null)
            {
                DescriptionAttribute attr =
                        Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                            typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (attr != null)
                    name = attr.Description;
            }
        }
        enumDL.Add(enm, name);
    }
    return enumDL;
}
```